# Pull data from the field

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `email` field in my database. Here I am getting it in `blade` page

```
<h3>Email: {{ $email }}</h3>
```

How can I pull off the value of this field so that I can edit it, or split it like this

```
<span data-first="me" data-second="example" data-third="com"></span>
```

Where `data` is my field `$email`

Comment: Maybe an option would be that you just add one or more a fields to your viewdata which are already split into the parts you need.

Comment: @user2190492 need to specifically get this field and split it, it is used in some other places and I cannot edit it in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to split `john@example.com` into three separate fields:

```
=> john
=> example
=> com
```

You can do the following using the PHP's [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function():

```
$split = explode('@', $email); // ['john', 'example.com']
$first = $split[0]; // 'john'
$second = explode('.', $split[1])[0]; // 'example'
$third = explode('.', $split[1])[1]; // 'com'
```

I hope I got your question right, if not, let me know.

Comment: all right) now I want to use this separation to protect against spambots, can you tell me a good way?

Comment: You can post that as an another question, maybe someone else will have a better suggestion :)

Comment: all the same, there is still a question how to apply this now, I supplemented the post with an example

Comment: how can I put everything together correctly?